# Not able to use linterconfigs command

Tags: linter, schemacrawler

I want to use Schemacrawler lint in my project and wants to use custom lints only. Based on documentation , it says we can use command `-linterconfigs=[path to linter XML configuration file]` But when I tried creating XML configuration file and use the custom lints only, I still see default linters are running. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Here is the steps I followed:

1. download and unzip the package
2. create dump database named example.database
3. created schemacrawler-linter-configs.xml with one of the existing lint
4. Using following command to run the lint on dump database from _schemacrawler directory

`./schemacrawler.sh --server=postgresql -command=lint -linterconfigs=schemacrawler-linter-configs.xml -database=example.database`

Answer (score 0):

Rashmi, SchemaCrawler runs all linters by default. You need to turn off any linters you don't need in the linters config file. Here is an example of how you can do it:

```xml
<schemacrawler-linter-configs>
  <linter id="schemacrawler.tools.linter.LinterForeignKeyMismatch">
    <run>false</run>
  </linter>
</schemacrawler-linter-configs>
```

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: we want to run the schemacrawler lint as part of travis build. Is there any documentation available for integration with travis ?